# How to substitute dataframe values matching on ID and performing different computation by column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

The problem is the following:
I have a data frame that I need to update inside a loop. The simple data frame has 4 columns: an identifier and four numeric columns. Here is the simple data frame at the initial step,

```
res_df <- data.frame(id = c("X", "Y", "Z"), 
                     count = NA, 
                     total = NA, 
                     value = NA)
```

At every iteration a new data frame is generated with the same identifier and the same numeric columns.
For instance,

```
loop_df <- data.frame(id = c("X", "Z"), 
                      count = c(1, 0),
                      total = c(20, 0),
                      value = c(0.05, 0))
```

I actually need to fill the `res_df` with information from the `loop_df` in the following way:

1. the row in `loop_df` with id "X" have to be inserted into the corresponding row of `res_df`, etc;
2. the column `count` has to be filled performing a simple sum between the values of the `res_df` and the newest values in the `loop_df` (essentially `sum(res_df$count, loop_df$count)` based on `id`);
3. the column `total` has to be filled in the same way of the column `count` (i.e. with a simple sum of the values based on `id`);
4. the column `value` has to be filled performing a simple average between the values of the `res_df` and the newest values in the `loop_df` (essentially `mean(res_df$count, loop_df$count)` based on `id`).

Here is how the **result** should be **after the first run**:

```
res_df   
id    count    total    value
X     1        20       0.05
Y     NA       NA       NA
Z     0        0        0
```

Now, suppose to be in the **second iteration** of the loop that results in the `loop_df` as follow

```
loop_df <- data.frame(id = c("X", "Y"), 
                      count = c(1, 0),
                      total = c(50, 0),
                      value = c(2.35, 0))
```

Then, **the `res_df` has to be updated as follows**

```
res_df   
id    count    total    value
X     2        70       1.2
Y     0        0        0
Z     0        0        0
```

**Update: Solution**

```
library(dplyr)
res_df <- arrange(res_df, id)
df_new_info <- arrange(loop_df, id)
ids <- loop_df$id

res_df[res_df$id %in% ids,] <- res_df[res_df$id %in% ids,] %>%
   mutate(count = case_when(is.na(count) ~ loop_df$count,
                            TRUE ~ count + loop_df$count),
          total = case_when(is.na(total) ~ loop_df$total,
                            TRUE ~ total + loop_df$total),
          value = case_when(is.na(value) ~ loop_df$value,
                            TRUE ~ ewise_mean(value, loop_df$value, zero.rm = TRUE))
         )
```

However, I am still looking for a solution which is highly efficient.

I'd really appreciate your help and thoughts about that.

Comment: Could you clarify how you expect `res_df` to be updated? In 4. you state "the column `value` has to be filled performing a simple average between the values of the res_df and the newest values in the loop_df (essentially mean(res_df$count, loop_df$count) based on id)." However `c(res_df$count[res_df$id == "X"], loop_df$count[loop_df$id == "X"])` evaluates to `c(1,2)`. And `mean(c(1,2))` is 1.5, not 1.2.

Comment: @IanCampbell thanks for your reply. The `value` column has to be filled with the mean between the values in `res_df$value` and the values in `loop_df$value`, i.e. `mean(df_res$value, loop_df$value)`.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt quite catch why you need the for loop to generate those `loop_df`, you might want to consider using `lapply` to get a list of `loop_df` and then use the following to get your desired result:

```
rbindlist(dfl)[, .(count=sum(count), total=sum(total), value=mean(value)), id]
```

output:

```
   id count total value
1:  X     2    70   1.2
2:  Z     0     0   0.0
3:  Y     0     0   0.0
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dfl <- list(
    setDT(data.frame(id = c("X", "Z"), 
        count = c(1, 0),
        total = c(20, 0),
        value = c(0.05, 0))),
    setDT(data.frame(id = c("X", "Y"), 
        count = c(1, 0),
        total = c(50, 0),
        value = c(2.35, 0)))
)
```

Comment: thatk you for your reply. The for loop is needed in my process because the `loop_df` is the final result of a lot of things. Actually I need to store the results obtained in `loop_df` into the `res_df` at each iteration.

Comment: am i correct to say that `loop_df` also depends on `res_df` from the prev iteration?

Comment: No, `loop_df` has only the very same columns but it is generated independently from `res_df` at each iteration. At the very beginning `res_df` is simply initialized with `NA` as I pointed out in the question.

Comment: anyway, I appreciated your solution since I can do actually a simple `rbind` of `res_df` and `loop_df` each time, and then `group by` `id` and `summarise` with the appropriate function.